# ADFS OpenId integration in .NET API results in Stackoverflow

Tags: authentication, .net-core, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, adfs

#### Background

I am working on a web application that consists of a separate API (.NET 7) and Front-end (NextJS / React). In short: the front-end calls the API to fetch information that should be displayed.

The authentication and authorization should go through Single Sign-on (SSO). The client has a on-premise ADFS server (Windows Server 2019). So far I have managed to setup ADFS to work with the front-end application to actually log in and obtain a JSON Web Token.

For this I have create a Application Group:

[image: The application group I created]

The Front-end uses [NextAuth](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/providers/oauth#using-a-custom-provider) to authenticate users via the oAuth 2.0 / OpenID Connect protocol by automatically redirect to the ADFS authentication page where the user logs in with their AD-account. This is working fine.

#### What I am trying

Now that the front-end is secured, I want to secure the API as well. As far as my understanding of ADFS goes, the front-end should use JWT as a Bearer token when calling the API which then should validate the token using ADFS. So I am trying to setup the connection between the .NET API and ADFS.

#### The problem

When accessing **any** route (also anonymous!), the console of the API is **massively** spamming exceptions. In fact: its a Stack Overflow exception:

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: /app
Stack overflow.
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCacheKey, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].FindValue(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCacheKey)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCacheKey, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].TryGetValue(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCacheKey, System.__Canon ByRef)
   at DynamicClass.ResolveService(ILEmitResolverBuilderRuntimeContext, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(System.Type, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]](System.IServiceProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions.GetAuthenticationService(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions.AuthenticateAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext, System.String)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1+<HandleAuthenticateAsync>d__13[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1+<HandleAuthenticateAsync>d__13[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]](<HandleAuthenticateAsync>d__13<System.__Canon> ByRef)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].Start[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1+<HandleAuthenticateAsync>d__13[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]](<HandleAuthenticateAsync>d__13<System.__Canon> ByRef)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].HandleAuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1+<AuthenticateAsync>d__48[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext()
```

This continues until the app finally crashes.

#### What I have done so far

OpenID Connect / oAuth 2.0 and definitely ADFS are new concepts for me. I do understand the basics, but I find it very difficult to find useful examples with ADFS within a .NET API. They are usually Azure AD or .NET Framework.

By scraping all kinds of sources, I was able to produce the following code:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "Bearer";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "Bearer";
})
.AddOpenIdConnect("Bearer", options =>
{
    options.ClientId = configuration["ClientId"];
    options.Authority = configuration["Authority"];
    options.MetadataAddress = configuration["MetadataAddress"];
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidAudiences = new[] { options.ClientId }
    };
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false; // Set this to true in production environments
});
```

- The **ClientID** matches the ID of the *Server application* inside the Application Group as this is the only application with a Client ID.
- The **Authority** is in this format: `https://adfs.<company>.local/adfs`
- The **MetadataAddress** is in this format: `https://adfs.<company>.local/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml`. I *do* know that OpenID uses the `.well-known/openid-configuration` format, but examples using this code use the XML file.

An important note I think is that the ADFS-server is using a **self-signed certificate** as this is a local testserver.

#### My question

I have no clue where the issue is located. It could be a wrong ADFS configuration due to my limited understanding, it could be a code issue. The only theory I can think of is that it has something to do with the self-signed certificate, but I don't know how to 'trust' or bypass it apart from the `RequireHttpsMetadata` option.

If anyone has an idea of what could be wrong, please let me know! This topic seems very limited to the enterprise world, as I can only find a *very* limited amount of online examples with similar situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Tore's answer and comments have pointed me into the right direction, thanks! I have to treat the Front and Backend differently. Since my solution is not exactly the same as Tore suggested, I will answer my question myself.

The Front-end has not changed and is still using OpenID to let the sign in using the ADFS Sign In page. This was and is stil working.

The Back-end however should *not* be using OpenID, but use the JWT Bearer token that was generated by the Front-end instead. I ended up with the following solution:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.Audience = "microsoft:identityserver:<SERVER_APP_CLIENT_ID>";
    options.Authority = "https://adfs.<company>.local/adfs";
    options.MetadataAddress = "https://adfs.<company>.local/adfs/.well-known/openid-configuration";
                
    // Ignore HTTPS in development only!
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                
    // Use the public key of ADFS to validate the JSON Web Token.
    var publicCert = new X509Certificate2("adfs_pkey.cer");
                
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidIssuer  = "http://adfs.<company>.local/adfs/services/trust",
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
                    
        RequireExpirationTime = true,
        RequireSignedTokens = true,
            
        IssuerSigningKey = new X509SecurityKey(publicCert),
    };
                
    // Ignore the self-signed certificate (only in development!)
    options.BackchannelHttpHandler = new HttpClientHandler { ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = delegate { return true; } };
});
```

*Hardcoded values will be moved to a configuration file ;-)*

As you can see: the only thing I do is simply validate the Bearer token on issuer, audience, signature and expiration.

Another important step - for me atleast - is to validate the Bearer token signature using the public key from ADFS (RSA256). *I do know that it is best practice to store those keys in key vaults*.

Thats is. This way the API is able to correctly validate the Bearer token generated by the Front-end using SSO (or directly via Postman) to secure the Back-end as well!

Answer (score 1):

First, I would rename Bearer to something else, like

```
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
```

Bearer, I typically use for the AddJwtBearer handler.

Second, the AddAuthentication seems wrong, as OpenIDConnect is only associated with the Challenge phase, everything else is typically handled by the AddCookie handler.

like:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddCookie(opt =>
{
   //...
}).AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
   //...
});
```

Comment: Interesting! But don't cookies make the API un-RESTfull? I assume a bearer token is still used to authenticate the request and that OpenId validates the token?

Comment: You need to separate the client application from the API. The client app uses AddOpenIDConnect(for logging in the user)+AddCookies(for creating the user session). The API, only needs AddJwtBearer, as it only needs to listen for incoming Access tokens and it does not use the AddOpenIDConnect. I got some blog post about this here https://nestenius.se/

Comment: After some trial and error I have managed to fix it by focussing on the JWT token. Thanks!

Comment: What whas the problem? and feel free to accept my answer if it helped you on your journey :)

Comment: I have published my own answers based on the direction you pointed me in! Thanks :)